# How do I make Github show the latest tag as the default view?

Tags: git, github

I learnt about tags after I'd started committing to a github project. What I used to do was:

```
git push origin master
```

Now, I'll do:

```
git tag -a v0.0.5 -m "version 0.0.5"
git push origin v0.0.5
```

This works in that it is uploaded fine, but the default view of the repo on the Github webpage is still of the untagged master. Is there a way to get it to show the latest tag by default, or do I also have to just push the master again in the untagged way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think github allows this kind of settings, but I have accomplished to always load the last tag in my master branch by following some useful guidelines described by Vincent Driessen in his article [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

If you look the `main branches` section you will see how the `master` is always used for successful releases, and as a result, you will always end up with the last tag being shown in your `github` main page.

NOTE:
Also, you can create a "releases" `branch` as well, set it up as the default branch on github, and use it to have your releases/tags instead of the master.

Comment: thanks, very helpful link. I like the idea of just merging into the master branch, it would appear that will make things straightforward. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You create a ref called `released` or similar and point it to the latest tag every time you make a new one.  Then force push that ref and set it as the default branch.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is a good idea but I prefer the other solution slightly better so it got the tick. I appreciate the help.